# Tensorflow CNN zero accuracy?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of 25000 colored pictures 100*100(*3) and I am trying to build a simple neural network with one convolutional layer. Its pictures of cells that are infected or not by Malaria, so my output is 2. But for every batch, I get 0% accuracy. My batchs are of size 1, but I tried with other size and I am still getting 0% accuracy.

My CNN :

```py
def simple_nn(X_training, Y_training, X_test, Y_test):
    input = 100*100*3
    h1 = 100
    batch_size = 1
    learning_rate = 0.000001
    dropout = 0.2

    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 100, 100, 3], name="is_train")
    Y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])

    #Layers
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(X, filters=64, kernel_size=4,
                         strides=2, padding='SAME',
                         activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv1")
    conv1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv1)
    conv1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1, 2, 2)

    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, filters=128, kernel_size=3,
                         strides=2, padding='SAME',
                         activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv2")
    conv2 = tf.layers.dropout(conv2, rate=dropout)

    conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv2, filters=256, kernel_size=3,
                     strides=2, padding='SAME',
                     activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv3")
    conv3 = tf.layers.dropout(conv3, rate=dropout)

    conv4 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv3, filters=64, kernel_size=3,
                     strides=2, padding='SAME',
                     activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv4")
    conv4 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv4, 2, 2)

    conv5 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv4, filters=32, kernel_size=3,
                         strides=2, padding='SAME',
                         activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv5")
    Y = tf.reshape(conv5, [batch_size,-1])
    logits = tf.layers.dense(Y, units=2, activation=tf.nn.relu)

    # loss function
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=Y_, logits=logits)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(cross_entropy, tf.float32))

    # % of correct answers found in batch
    is_correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y,1), tf.argmax(Y_,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(is_correct, tf.float32))


    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    train_step = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(math.floor(len(X_training)/batch_size)):
        st = batch_size * i
        end = st + batch_size

        if end >= math.floor(len(X_training)) - batch_size:
            break
        batch_X, batch_Y = X_training[st:end], Y_training[st:end]
        train_data={X: batch_X, Y_: batch_Y}

        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=train_data)

        #Get the accuracy and loss
        a, l = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy], feed_dict=train_data)
        print("acc : "+str(a)+" , loss : "+str(l))
```

My output :

```
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6931472]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6931472]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.69436306]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6931472]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6931662]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6931472]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6925567]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6931472]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6931472]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.69259375]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6912933]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6957785]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6931472]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6990725]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.69037354]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6931472]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6931472]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6931472]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6931472]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6991633]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6931472]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6931472]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6931472]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.700589]
acc : 0.0 , loss : [0.6931472]
```

I was getting 65% (meaning `acc=0.65`) with a simple not convolutionnal layer, but since I switched to conv, `acc=0.0`. First I through that for some reason, the accuracy was returned in my variable `loss` when using convolutionnal layers, but I don't think so now, something is wrong in my loss function I think.
And even if I reduce my model to one layer, the same thing is happenning, and my `loss` is still around `0.69`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should minimise over the reduced vector. Change this line

`train_step = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)`

to this:

`train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss)`

Also, you don't include `logits` layer in computation of accuracy. Do this:

```py
is_correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits,1), tf.argmax(Y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(is_correct, tf.float32))
```

Additionally, you are applying two activations to the `logits` layer. First you have `tf.nn.relu` and then you use `softmax` (with `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2()`). Not sure that you're doing it intentionally.

Comment: I am still getting the same output when I change this line, still 0.0 accuracy

Comment: @ZulHuky, There is another probable issue. Updated just now.

Comment: Thank you, now I don't have 0% accuracy anymore! But I have around 50% accuracy, that's another problem (My loss function is still giving me a value around 0.69 for each  batch)

Comment: @ZulHuky, Glad to help. Good luck with that!